# Comparing Attributes of an element

Tags: javascript, arrays, protractor

```
var DrpStack = browser.findElement(by.xpath(XPath))
             var Elems = DrpStack.findElements(by.tagName(TagName))
             Elems.then(function(list){ 
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    if (list[i].getAttribute("aria-pressed")=='true') {
                        Labl1.list[i].getAttribute("onlabel");

                    } else {
                        console.log("FAIL");
                    }
                }

                Q.all(Labl1).done(function (result) {
                    // Q.All will  print the results when the lookups and processing are done
                    console.log(result.length);
                    console.log(result);
                });
            });
```

Here i am checking if the attribute of 'aria-pressed' is true or false. If true that element is pushed in an array otherwise it should print false.
It does not work, the log always prints FAIL. What m i doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getAttribute` returns a Promise. So you first need to resolve it to get the value.

In your case you could filter the attribute with `promise.filter`:

```
var filter = protractor.promise.filter;

filter(browser.findElements(...), (elem, i) => {
  return elem.getAttribute("aria-pressed").then(attr => {
      if(attr === "true") return true;
      console.log(`failed attribute at index {i}`);
  });
}).then(results => {
  console.log("elements with attribute:", results);
});
```